# numpy で一次元配列の行列積を簡潔に表記したい

Tags: python, numpy

以下のコードは6✖️１行の行列と1✖️3の行列の積を計算する意図で書いたプログラムです。

`ab_result2` の行で計算はできましたが、可読性に欠ける気がしています。
できれば `ab_result1` のように簡潔に表記したいのですが、なぜか "value error" と表示されます。

この "value error" はなぜ発生するのでしょうか？
また、一次元配列同士の積はどのように書くのが可読性のよい記述になるのでしょうか？

質問とは逸れますが、`print(a.shape)` で表示される `(6,)` は6行✖️1の配列という意味であっていますか？
（形状(6,1)が(6,)とデフォルトで表記されてしまっているという理解であってますか？）

よろしくお願いします。

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
b = np.array([100,200,300])

print(a.shape) #(6,) ←これは6行✖️１の意味であってますか？（(6,1)と同じ意味？）
print(b.shape) #(3,)


ab_result1 = a* b.T　#6✖️１行の行列と1✖️3の行列の計算だがなぜこれでエラーがでるのか
ab_result2 = a.reshape(a.shape[0],1) * b.reshape(1,b.shape[0])

print(ab_result1)
print(ab_result2)

#出力
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6,) (3,)

[ 100  200  300]
 [ 200  400  600]
 [ 300  600  900]
 [ 400  800 1200]
 [ 500 1000 1500]
 [ 600 1200 1800]]
```

Comment: 出力結果から察するに、Kronecker product(クロネッカー積)を求めようとしているのでしょうか? `np.kron(a.reshape(-1, 1), b)`

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。クロネッカーの積を理解できていないのですが,,,やりたいこととしては表の左端に縦に[1,2,3,4,5,6]、一番上の行に[100,200,300]を並べて、それぞれの成分同士を掛け合わせた乗算表を出力することです。ab_result2のような出力を意図しています。伝わりにくかったら申し訳ありません。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/282324

Comment: 解決済みの様子。